# How to remove http://dx.doi.org string from doi field in BibTeX style?

Tags: bibtex

As I see it, most BibTeX styles (`.bst` files) assume that the `doi` field in a BibTeX databases (`.bib` files) is saved without a `http://dx.doi.org/` prefix. However, many scentific journals export bibtex recodrs with this prefix, eg,

```
doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1408625},
```

although

```
doi = {10.1063/1.1408625},
```

is expected by the most of the BibTeX styles.

As a result a standard BibTeX style fails to produce correct `doi` output. Is it possible to invent a `bibtex` function that would check if the prefix `http://dx.doi.org/` is already in the `doi` field value and append in only in the case when it is absent? If `.bst` style is not able for such manipulation, then it could pass the `doi` value to a LaTeX command that would make required check.

Comment: It would be easier to use search and replace to clean your `.bib` instead of messing with bibtex internals. Or let [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) do the job for you, e.g. `sed 's_http://dx.doi.org/__g' bibliography.bib`

Comment: Certainly the fault here is with the export: the DOI itself clearly doesn't contain the web link part. As @DG' says, it seems best to fix the data in the database.

Comment: What is the aim of banal advices to edit databse?

Comment: The aim is to fix it, where it is broken.

Comment: With `biblatex` you can make such changes on the fly.

Comment: I agree with @DG': BibTeX entries exported by scientific databases can almost never be taken "as is" – they simply contain too many errors (e.g., forced title capitalization, wrong escaping of special characters, ...). Basically, one has to edit them anyway, the doi-is-url issue is just another nuisance.